# Creating a two dimensional array from a file input in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, multidimensional-array, matrix

TL;DR: Struggling with 2 dimensional arrays.

I'm trying to create two two dimensional array from a list of integers from a text file. This is programmed in C.

tester.txt contains:

```
2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

The first number means that both arrays have 2 rows and 2 columns, if it were any other number the columns/rows would be represented as such.

tester.txt should ouput the following:

```
1 2    5 6
3 4    7 8
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    FILE *filepointer;
    int nrows;
    int size;

    fputs("Enter a filename: ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    if ( fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin) != NULL )
    {
        char *newline = strchr(filename, '\n'); /* search for newline character */
        if ( newline != NULL )
        {
            *newline = '\0'; /* overwrite trailing newline */
        }
        printf("filename = \"%s\"\n", filename);
    }

    filepointer=fopen(filename,"r");
    fseek(filepointer, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
    size = ftell(filepointer);
    printf("Size=%d\n",size);
    fseek(filepointer, 0, SEEK_SET);

    int holderarray[size];

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        fscanf(filepointer, "%d", &holderarray[i]);

    nrows=holderarray[0];
    printf("Number of rows/columns=%d\n",nrows);

    if (filepointer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected up until this point. I can't visualize how to add the first half of the values to the new 2 dimensional arrays, hopefully you guys can help. Here's my brainstorming in codeblocks.

```
int matrix1[nrows][nrows];
int matrix2[nrows][nrows];


for (i=1; i<sizeof(holderarray);i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<nrows;j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]=holderarray[j];
    }

for (i=0;i<sizeof(nrows);i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<sizeof(nrows);j++)
    {
        printf("%d",matrix[i][j]);
    }

}
return 0;
```

Comment: Your holder-array is being sized to the byte-count of the file; not the number of integers within.  If this is intentional as a mechanism for ensuring you don't overrun a short array it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: oh I had no idea, how do I size by number of integers within?

Comment: You don't. This is a txt file. you need to process the character data within, translating to the native data types you need (in your case, `int`s).Creative use of `scanf()` after reading the number chars (and translating to your `int` matrix size, of course), would make for a fairly straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can get them by looping using getc

```
1. you read the first char in line and define the array structure , cast to integer 
2. initialize the arrays  eg you read 2 so 2*2 is the size of the array, 3*3 is the size of the array and number of the elements to read in every array 
3. continue reading in to reach the first array bound based 2*2 = 4 3*3= 9 based on the first line. 

4. fill the other array since the first array is full,
```

Comment: Yeah ok, I understand how that would work. It's not three nested loops. I'm trying to visualize it, but I'm having a hard time/

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically declare arrays in standard C like this based on variables that aren't known at compile time:

```
int matrix1[nrows][nrows];
int matrix2[nrows][nrows];
```

What you need to do, if you aren't using C99 or a later version, is use the [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) function that dynamically allocates memory for you:

```
int **matrix1, **matrix2;
int i;

matrix1 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int*));
matrix2 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int*));

for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
  matrix1[i] = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int));
  matrix2[i] = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int));
}
```

Two-dimensional arrays in C are treated as pointers to pointers. Each pointer is a reference to a contiguous chunk of memory that contains integers (i.e. the rows of your matrix), and then we use a pointer to a pointer as a reference to another contiguous chunk of memory that contains references/pointers to the first element in all of these rows.

This image (not mine) may help: [DYNAMIC 2D ARRAY](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ce4hgph2lJ4/TsLgdbwtg7I/AAAAAAAABms/JsSceuX4IZo/s1600/array_2d_dynamic.png)

Note that this dynamically allocated memory should be freed when you are finished using it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
  free(matrix1[i]);
  free(matrix2[i]);
}

free(matrix1);
free(matrix2);
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, but by the time we reach int matrix1[nrows][nrows], nrows is instantiated.

Comment: That works only if you are using C99, so make sure you have the -std=c99 flag when compiling. Sorry for being unclear; I'll edit my answer.